# display プロパティが @keyframes を用いたアニメーションで動作しない理由は？

Tags: css

CSS でフェードアウト効果のアニメーションを作成しています。

フェードアウト後に要素を消すため、 `@keyframes` に `display: none` を設定しましたが、フェードアウト完了後も要素が消えず、透明になったまま残ってしまいます。問題の再現する `@keyframes` は次のようになっています:

```css
@keyframes fade-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

実際に動かしてみると、期待通りに動作しているように見えますが、フェードアウト完了後にテキスト周辺をドラッグすると**テキストを選択出来る**ので、 `display` プロパティが動作していないことがわかります。

```css
.text-box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  animation: fade-out 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-box">
  テキスト
</div>
```

`@keyframes` 内の `display` プロパティはどのように動作するのでしょうか？また、この問題はどうすれば解決出来ますか？

Answer (score 4):

Web Animations によれば、`@keyframes` 内にアニメーションが不可能であるプロパティが存在した場合、それは**無視されます**<sup>[[1]](https://www.w3.org/TR/web-animations-1/#animating-properties)</sup>。今回の場合、 `display` プロパティは**アニメーションが不可能**<sup>[[2]](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#the-display-properties)</sup>であるため、フェードアウト用アニメーションの `display` プロパティは無視され、動作しません。

> #### 5.2. Animating properties <sup>[[1]](https://www.w3.org/TR/web-animations-1/#animating-properties)</sup>
>
> **not animatable**
> The property is not animatable. It is not processed when listed in an animation keyframe, and is not affected by transitions.

---

この問題を解決するための一つの解決策として、アニメーションの終了するタイミングで JavaScript により `display: none` を設定する、という方法があります。

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  setTimeout(() => document.querySelector(".text-box").style.display = "none", 3000);
});
```

```css
.text-box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  animation: fade-out 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-box">
  テキスト
</div>
```

もしくは、 `position`, `width`, `height`, `overflow` プロパティなどを用いて、**見かけ上は要素が消えたように見せる**という方法もあります。しかし、要素は依然としてドキュメントツリー上に残っており、設定された `margin` や `padding` プロパティなどの影響も受けるため、**使用出来る場面が限定**されます。

```css
.text-box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  animation: fade-out 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    position: static;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-box">
  テキスト
</div>
```